# Structuring database for CakePHP - relationship based on join table

Tags: mysql, database-design, cakephp-3.x

I am designing a database for use with CakePHP 3, but I am having trouble figuring out how to set up and define a particular relationship.

I have 'Contracts' which can have multiple 'Properties', but each Contract<->Property relationship can have multiple 'ContractEvents'. Normally I would join the 'contract_events' table to the 'contracts_properties' table but I can't seem to figure out how to get CakePHP to recognise this or whether this is the correct convention.

Here is a diagram trying to illustrate what I want:

```
Contracts <- Join Table -> Properties
                 |
                 v
           ContractEvents
```

Apologies if this is unclear or a dupe, I wasn't really sure how to phrase it when searching. Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option

Comment: That, plus an association to contact events in the join table class, and your contracts table would need an additional has-many association to the join table class, so that you can contain the events when querying the contracts.